# Code Review Secret Santa 2015: Unveil yourself!

Tags: discussion, fun

Since we've been using meta to follow the steps of the first Code Review Secret Santa, I thought it would be fair to use the meta to reveal your identity to your <s>victim</s> recipient.

I think that discovering who was our Secret Santa would create stronger bonds between the community! :)

So let's go, post as an answer who's Santa you were!

References:

[Code Review's Secret Santa 2015](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6263/code-reviews-secret-santa-2015?s=1|1.0751)

[Code Review Secret Santa 2015: Show off your gifts](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6350/code-review-secret-santa-2015-show-off-your-gifts?s=3|0.7383)

Answer (score 8):

## rolfl

You said you liked books, but I didn't want to get you a programming book (I feel certain you already have a whole lot of them). You said you liked "mementos" of sorts, things that represent a place in some way. You also said you liked photography.

So I thought I would combine some of those things, and give you a photo and history book about Louisville, Kentucky, my "home away from home" :-)

Comment: I have to tell you that the history of Louisville is far more colourful than I expected, it has been a delight to read, and I have shared it around once already. It's perfect for me, and I really do appreciate it. Some of the stories are ridiculous, funny, and tragic, sometimes all at the same time. Thanks, and appreciated.

Answer (score 8):

## Dan Pantry

Surprise! (I was dumb enough to add a signed personal note, so nothing left to be revealed.) Picked something from your wish list to make sure you get something you actually like, + something I strongly recommend (Zero To One), as a surprise. I hope you're enjoying your gifts!

Comment: I am! Very useful books :-)

Answer (score 8):

### Janos

Yup, you guessed right. I read the GoF book last century, and again this one, and it is one of those timeless classics which are hard to find in the computing world. It still makes sense, and it's a valuable resource (So useful that [googling GoF](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=GoF) takes you right to it .... ;-)

The Hacker's Delight is another favourite of mine, and it has a lot of technical detail that's also timeless, but for different reasons - it's so low level that as long as there are bits and bytes, there'll be a reason to read it.

Hope you find them both useful, and that they teach you something new.

Comment: Absolutely useful timeless classics, and lots of interesting things to learn, thanks a lot for the thought, it was a really special Christmas!

Answer (score 6):

## Joe Wallis

Joe Wallis, I've been Secret Santa'ing you! :)

I hope you enjoyed your gift and the Secret Santa experience. I think I've had just as much fun shopping on Amazon UK than receiving my own gift :p

Answer (score 6):

## Quill

Shipping an anonymous gift to the other side of the planet has been pretty thrilling! I'm such a big mouth though, I'm pretty sure you already figured out I'm the one that sent you Robert C. Martin's *Clean Code* - I hope you enjoyed it, it's a book you'll keep referring to, both in coding and in reviewing.

Answer (score 6):

## Zak

Asking you questions about your picture, board games and *dragons* was enjoyable.
Unfortunately custom rubber ducks are surprisingly expensive,
so I went out on a limb and got you dragons,
I hope you enjoy HTTYD enough to enjoy them!
As I'm sure you know, I'm not a big board gamer, so I hope you enjoy the game too!

Answer (score 6):

## TopinFrassi

Apologies that it came so late.. I did order it several weeks before it arrived, I won't be ordering from where I bought it again :-)

On the upside you now have approximately one DeskByte worth of Cloud Storage!

Comment: Don't worry about the delay :p I thought you were my Santa when I received my gift! Thanks, I love my gift :p

Comment: This one was actually my favorite when I went through the gift picture thread. Awesome!

Answer (score 6):

### Mat's Mug

Surprise! I did actually consider getting you a new keyboard, but figured something that personal should really be left to individual choice. Enjoy the books!

Comment: Wah! So *you're* the millionaire Santa! The books are awesome! ...I wasn't *really* expecting a new guitar or a keyboard ;-)

Comment: Did I mention I work in the Investment Industry ^^

Answer (score 6):

## Mast

Hello! I had a hard time deciding what to get you at first, but when you added What-If XKCD to your wishlist I knew I had to get it for you, as I had read it myself.

I hope you enjoy[ed] the book! It's definitely a great read. :)

Answer (score 6):

## Phrancis

I knew you liked old-school games. Bought your gift from an artist not too many states from your location.

Have fun with it, whether you want to keep it as a trophy or actually put it to use. It should be of decent quality.

Comment: It looks beautiful and it's certainly being put to good use!

Answer (score 5):

## Ethan Bierlein

I hope you enjoy your books, it was a bit weird for me because I don't do C++, but I had some help.

I hope they serve you well on your way to C++ wizardry :-)